# Rails 3: Importing records and their has_many associations from one app to another using json

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json

Let's assume I've got two Rails apps with databases having the exact same schema and models. I want to be able to import some records from one database to the other. For example, what if I've got an Students table, and would like to retrieve one student from one db to the other?

I've been sending the student json representation (`self` is a student):

```
student_json = self.as_json(:include => [
                                 { :final_grade_batches => { :include => { :final_grade => { :include => :gradeable } } } }
                            ])
```

from app 2 to app 1. This works when I don't include associations defined with has_many, but when I do, as in the example above, I receive the following message instantiating the student (`Student.new(params[:student])`) where params[:student] is the json retrieved from the other app:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: FinalGradeBatch(#2159093540) expected, got Hash(#2151972720)
```

Of course, I've got `has_many :final_grade_batches` in the Student Model.

Any help? Thanks!